# adding to a column without creating NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Master DataFrame  with 6 rows.  I want to add the values from several other DataFrames to the pl column, but the other DataFrames will have a subset of the rows.  **I don't want to create NaN values in the missing rows.**   Here's the Master dataframe:

```
             pl
Date           
2010-01-27  7.0
2010-01-28  7.0
2010-01-29  7.0
2010-02-01  7.0
2010-02-02  7.0
2010-02-03  7.0
```

Here's the DateFrame from which I'd like to add to the Master

```
                 edge
Date                 
2010-01-28   6.747998
2010-01-29   4.497736
2010-02-01   6.977076
2010-02-02  10.016789
```

Here is my code:

```
    df_master.pl += df_y.edge
```

Here's the (unwanted) result:

```
                   pl
Date                 
2010-01-27        NaN
2010-01-28  13.747998
2010-01-29  11.497736
2010-02-01  13.977076
2010-02-02  17.016789
2010-02-03        NaN
```

I want my sevens back!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `add`

```
df_master.pl = df_master.pl.add(df_y.edge, fill_value=0)
```

Comment: That worked splendidly.   Thank you.   I can't click the checkmark for another 12 minutes.

Comment: @TPM yw:-) happy coding